# getAttribute isn't return correct value

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have this:

```
<body>
    <div id=myid0 i='Keliot'> 0</div>
    <div id=myid1 i='Ukonh'>     1</div>
    <div id=myid2 i='plotis'> 2</div>
</body>
```

I am trying to get the value of `i` but I am getting null for `myid0`. This is what I am using:

```
alert(document.getElementById('myid0').getAttribute('i'));
```

The error is:

> Error: 'document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object

Comment: Is something wrong with your Enter key?

Comment: Your code doesn't demonstrate any particular issue that would cause that Error. Please update the question with a broader picture of the actual code you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you place the code *after* the elements you're selecting so they exist when you try to select them.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/dS4t5/

```
<body>
    <div id=myid0 i='Keliot'> 0</div>
    <div id=myid1 i='Ukonh'>     1</div>
    <div id=myid2 i='plotis'> 2</div>

    <!-- script is placed here, after the elements have loaded -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert(document.getElementById('myid0').getAttribute('i'));
    </script>
</body>
```

---

As noted by [@typo.pl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/524566/typo-pl), this is only one way to make sure the DOM elements exist.

You can place the code in a function, and call it from `body onload="myfunc();"`, or from `window.onload = myfunc;`. Or you could use a less precise method of setting a timer with `setTimeout` to execute the code.

Comment: Or have the code executed after the browser has parsed those elements - try at BODY.onload time or later (say via a setTimeout call)

Comment: And to add to this: it's better to use the convention of prefixing custom data attributes with `data-` (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes).

Comment: @Marcel: Definitely worth noting.

Comment: BTW, "after the elements have been closed" seems to be a better description to me.

Comment: @Marcel: Hmmm... Perhaps after the *tag* has been closed. An element is (in my mind) typically a reference to the resulting host object that is generated after parsing the HTML tags.

Comment: @Marcel:...well I guess I shouldn't make such a distinction since the HTML spec refers to them as elements.

Comment: I can see the page infront of me downloaded. I even put a button and onclick tried to get the value and it didnt work either. so not sure if timer has anything to do with it. I also have onload

Comment: @user: Please post the actual code you're using so we don't need to guess at the cause of the issue.

Comment: About tags vs. elements: that's not correct: you can't close a tag; in this case `<div>blah</div>`, `div` is an element. `<div>` alone is a tag, as is `</div>` (a closing tag). And `<br />` is a self-closing element. See [Tag is not an element. Or is it?](http://perfectionkills.com/tag-is-not-an-element-or-is-it/) Please also read [Bobince's comment](http://perfectionkills.com/tag-is-not-an-element-or-is-it/#comment-60500).

Comment: @Marcel: Yep, you're right. As I noted above, the spec clearly states that they're elements. I'll be careful to keep that distinction straight and clear in the future. And thanks for the link to the excellent article.

Answer (score 0):

Put quotes around your id attributes:

```
<body>
    <div id='myid0'>0</div>
    <div id='myid1'>1</div>
    <div id='myid2'>2</div>
</body>
```

Also, I would advise against creating custom element attributes.  i is not a standard xHTML element attribute.

Comment: Which one of those issues would cause the Error OP is asking about?

Comment: With the limited amount of code/info provided, who knows what's causing it..  I'm just trying to point out some obvious issues that are invalidating the markup (according to standards).